# Convolution integral identity proof

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

How can one show that $$ f * g = t^{m+n+1} \int_0^1 u^m(1-u)^n du $$ where $f(t) = t^m$, $g(t) = t^n$ and $$f*g = \int_0^t f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau = \int_0^t f(t-\tau)g(\tau)d\tau $$

I tried with the binomial theorem on $(t-\tau)^n$ but to no avail. Unable to progress from here.

Comment: Substitute $\tau = t\cdot u$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
f \star g(t) = \int_0^t \tau^m (t-\tau)^n\, d\tau
$$

Now with $\tau  =ut$, you get
$$
f \star g(t) = \int_0^1 (ut)^m (t-ut)^n t\,du = t^{m+n+1}\int_0^1 u^m (1-u)^n \,du
$$